# Regular expression for special character $

Tags: java, regex

I have a string "any tag$@ws2-role$@ws1-role" and I want to have a regular expression to search a word starting with "$@" and ending either with "$@" or with end of a line.

For example, for the above input, the output has to be ws2-role and ws1-role.

I tried below regular expression but I am not able to figure out how to add or operator for pattern2 so that it can also consider end of line for giving the output e.g $@|$. $@ is the exact word to be match and $ to look until the end of line.

```
String pattern1 = "$@";
String pattern2 = "$@";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(pattern2));
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tag);
    // check all occurance
    while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

Can anyone gives some hints?

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Anubhava, the regular expression "\\$@\\S+(?=\\$@|$)" gives "$@ws2-role$@ws1-role" as a single matched group but I want to have ws2-role and ws1-role as two matched groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$@([^\\$@]+|$)");
CharSequence tag = "any tag$@ws2-role$@ws1-role";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tag);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
ws2-role
ws1-role
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookahead based regex for this:

```
String regex = "\\$@\\S+(?=\\$@|$)";
```